# Polynomials $f(x)$ such that $f(x)f(x-1)+f(x^2)=0$

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations

How can I find all polynomials $f(x)$ such that $f(x)f(x-1)+f(x^2)=0?$ I am self-studying functional equations, but don't know how to start this one. A hint would suffice.

Comment: How about $f(x)=-x^2-x-1$ ? Does it work?

Comment: Yes it works. How did you get that?

Comment: Haha...I actually used trial and error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Observe that for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a)=0$, we also have $f(a^2)=0$ and $f((a+1)^2)=0$. This will lead to infinitely many roots unless.....

Comment: @arabhimanachra No unless $a=a^2$ or $a=(a+1)^2$ or $a^2=(a+1)^2$.