# Find all the polynomials $f$ that satisfy $f(x^2)+f(x)f(x+1)=0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, functional-equations

find all the polynomial f that satisfies $f(x^2)+f(x)f(x+1)=0$.

I'm not sure if I'm doing it in the right way and I'm confused.
So I tried to write something like this. 
let $z_1,z_2,z_3,...,z_n$ be n complex roots of f(x), and they're not zeros.
when $x = z_i, i \in {1,2,..,n}$ then $f(x^2) = 0$, giving us that $z_i^2 \in {z_1,z_2,..,z_n}$. By this, we can obtain that $z_i^{2k} \in {z_1,z_2,...,z_n}$, and this means $|z_1| = |z_2| = .. = |z_n| = 1$. 
However, because $z_1 -1, z_2 -1,..,z_n -1$ are roots of $f(x+1)$. 
when we let x be $z_1 -1, z_2 -1,..,z_n -1$, $f((z_i-1)^2) = 0$, meaning that $(z_i -1)^2 \in {z_1,z_2,..,z_n}$. but if $|z_i| = 1$, doesn't that means $|(z_i-1)^2|$ can't be 1?
which means that is question has only one f,$f(x) = 0$? 
I think I was wrong at some steps.I'm confused. Please leave any suggestion you have, it will be really helpful.

Comment: Can you solve for $ |z| = 1 , |z -1 | = 1$? EG Draw the locus in the complex plane, are there points of intersection?

Comment: Since you said $\{z_i\}$ are the non-zero roots of $f$, $f((z_i-1)^2) = 0$ means $(z_i-2)^2 \in \{0, z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n\}$. And don't forget that certain polynomials have no roots at all.

Comment: well, no roots even in the complex number plane? humm., I didn't know that before.

Comment: $f(x)=-1$ has no roots at all and satisfies your functional equation.

Comment: Those "certain polynomials" are polynomials of degree zero, aka constant functions. (Except the zero function.)

Comment: Also, invariance of the set of roots under squaring does not imply that all its members must have unit norm. Zero is invariant under squaring, too!

Comment: yeah, I think you're right. this should be considered as one of the case where f(x) is constant function. I didn't think of that.

Comment: Thank you! that's another thing I didn't see.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all polynomials $f(x)$ satisfying $f(x^2 ) + f(x) \cdot f(x + 1) = 0$ ∀ $x ∈ R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3962174/find-all-polynomials-fx-satisfying-fx2-fx-cdot-fx-1-0-%e2%88%80-x)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Zero-set

You have correctly identified two transformations which send roots of $f$ to roots of $f$. Explicitly, setting $u(z)=z^2$ and $v(z)=(z-1)^2$, we have $u(S)\subset S$ and $v(S)\subset S$. Let's examine what this tells us about $S$.

First, note that $u(S)\subset S$ implies that $|z|\in\{0,1\}$ for every $z\in S$. Suppose that $S$ contains roots with absolute value in $(0,1)$ and let $w$ be a root with the smallest absolute value in $(0,1)$. Then $|w|^2<|w|$. The contradiction implies that no $w\in S$ has absolute value in $(0,1)$. Analogous argument shows that $S$ does not contain any elements with absolute value greater than $1$.

Second, note that the first fact above together with $v(S)\subset S$ imply that $S\subset\{0,1\}$. We have $v(v(S))\subset S$ and
$$
((z-1)^2-1)^2=(z^2-2z+1-1)^2=z^2(z-2)^2.\tag1
$$
However, the unit circle has diameter two, so the only $z$ with $|z|\in\{0,1\}$ that also satisfy $|z|\cdot|z-2|\in\{0,1\}$ are $z=0$ and $z=1$. Therefore, $S\subset\{0,1\}$.

### Leading coefficient

Let $a$ denote the leading coefficient of $f(x)$. The functional equation implies that $a+a^2=0$. Therefore, $a=-1$.

### Solution

The facts above imply that $f$ is of the form $f(x)=-x^n(x-1)^m$. Substituting into our functional equation we obtain
$$
\begin{align}
f(x^2)+f(x)f(x+1)=0\tag2\\
-x^{2n}(x^2-1)^m+x^n(x-1)^m(x+1)^nx^m=0\tag3\\
-x^{2n}(x-1)^m(x+1)^m+x^{n+m}(x-1)^m(x+1)^n=0\tag4\\
\end{align}
$$
which implies that $n=m$. Therefore, the set of polynomial solutions of the functional equation consists of $f(x)\equiv 0$ and $f(x)=-x^n(x-1)^n$ for $n=0,1,2,\dots$.

Comment: Thank you. Good explanation, really answer my question.